# What does 0xdd mean in a memory dump in MVS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I ran a snippet of C++ code in Microsoft Visual Studio and am tryomg to understand the export of Memory Dump.

The code is the following

```
Dummy* pA;
{
    Dummy* pB = new Dummy("Kostas");
    pA = pB;
}

delete pA;
pA = NULL;
```

When the line `delete pA` is executed, I see that the bytes where the `pA` shows are filled with `0xdd`.

Does hex dd have any special meaning?
[image]

Comment: As described in document linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/7034621) [0xDD is magic number for `free()`'d memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values)

Comment: Also, this only happens in DEBUG builds.